# Algorithm: Making an Optimal Kids Baseball Team That Satisfies Requests

Tags: algorithm, graph

Trying to write an algorithm, but I don't know much graph theory so all I have in my arsenal right now is branch and bound and a genetic algorithm. Not very robust, but I'm here to learn.

Here's My Problem:
We've got a set of n kids to be put into k teams with L players per team. Each kid requests a maximum of 3 friends to play on their team. Each kid is guaranteed that one of their requests is fulfilled.

I want to maximize the set of teams, such that we maximize the number of fulfilled requests, subject to the contraint of L players per team and each child has at least one fulfilled request.

What type of algorithm should I look into researching about? I imagine this is some application of graph theory with each player being a node and each request being an edge..but thats about the extent of my graph knowledge.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If it is, tag with `homework`, please =)

Comment: Its not! Just a friend of mine runs a league..asked me to help him out.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create the graph as you described, then apply Prim's algorithm (minimum spanning tree) to ensure at least one of every player's requests is fulfilled, then start at end nodes and traverse the graph to calculate the teams (ensuring that you break teams on players who will get two requests fulfilled.

This assumes that there will not be a number of subgraphs (ie two groups of players who request each other but none from the other group).  However, at least by running Prim's you can narrow down the field of which player gets paired with which friends.

Comment: What happens if your MST algorithm picks a star structure tree? (i.e. one node is connected to every other node). Since each edge is weighted equally, this is a possibility.

Comment: @ElKamina That's unlikely, but I see your point.  The other thing I didn't consider in my original answer is that edges should be directional (this player chooses that player), because a player could be picked by others but not have any of his or her choices fulfilled.

Comment: I would not consider it unlikely. It would depend on the small piece of logic used to pick the next edge (how will it handle equality? If it sorts by node number then this scenario is very likely). Anyways, the concern you mention is also very likely? How would you address it? You need to find a set of subgraphs that are connected, have at least one loop, and all nodes have a outgoing edge.